# service bus queue not triggering azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am getting an error

Function (FunctionApp120200507193944/Function1) Error: The binding type(s) 'serviceBusTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed. Session Id: 7dc83962fc064a66939fa98988d93543 Timestamp: 2020-05-07T15:50:51.441Z

please suggest.

Comment: can you share the code you have

Comment: Can you show your code? What version of azure function you are using now? And can you show the package you are using?

Comment: Hi,
I am using below in azure function
- "version": "2.0"

Comment: For Packages see : https://ibb.co/XDpZ2nQ

Comment: Code : https://github.com/sahilmanhas30/azurefunctions/find/master

Answer (score 0):

Check your function package picture, the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.7`  is not loaded. Then I download your function project, load it to vs then I found you are using .net core 2.1, so this is conflicted, you could update the .net core to .net core 3 or downgrade the function version to v2.

I have tried, just change the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to `1.0.36` then it will work.

[image]